# F# resolving deadlock

Tags: concurrency, f#

I'm very new to concurrency programming, so I have a small problem with deadlock that I need to solve.

So for this code below, it doesn't print anything out which I suspect there must be a deadlock, though I'm not quite sure how it happens.

```
let sleepMaybe() = if (random 4) = 1 then Thread.Sleep 5

type account(name:string) =
    let balance = ref 1000
    member this.Balance = lock this <| fun () -> !balance
    member this.Name = name
    member this.Withdraw amount = balance := !balance - (sleepMaybe(); amount)
    member this.Deposit amount  = balance := !balance + (sleepMaybe(); amount)

    member this.Transfer (toAcc:account) amount = 
        lock this <| fun () ->  lock toAcc <| fun () -> toAcc.Deposit amount
                                this.Withdraw amount


let doTransfers (acc:account) (toAcc:account) () = 
    for i in 1..100 do acc.Transfer toAcc 100
    printfn "%s balance: %d  Other balance: %d" acc.Name acc.Balance toAcc.Balance

let q2main() = 
    let acc1=account("Account1") 
    let acc2=account("Account2")

    startThread (doTransfers acc1 acc2)
    startThread (doTransfers acc2 acc1)

q2main()
```

Comment: You need to post your actual code.  This code doesn't work.

Comment: For example, it's not random, it's Random (and F# is case sensitive).  Plus there's no "startThread" that I know of but there is a Thread.Start.

Comment: As you can see from the answers using locks correctly is quite a challenge. As a long time C# abuser I'd recommend to learn how to use locks correctly, but then avoid them wherever possible. Most problems can be solved much easier by passing messages instead of shared state. Have a look at the MailboxProcessor in F#.

Comment: Thanks stmax, but I'm not at the stage of knowing how to use locks correctly, so I try to avoid using Mailbox in this as I personally find async is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are locking on the instances themselves and requiring that both instances be locked to transfer something. That is a recipe for deadlocks.

- Thread 1 locks on acc1 to begin a transfer
- Thread 2 locks on acc2 to begin a transfer
- Thread 1 waits for the lock on acc2 to be released so it can complete its transfer
- Thread 2 waits for the lock on acc1 to be released so it can complete its transfer

They will each wait for each other to let go of their lock indefinitely.

If you *have* to acquire multiple locks at once, *always* acquire the locks in the same order. That said, try your best not to need more than one lock at once by changing your object responsibilities.

For example, withdrawal and depositing are two separate actions that aren't related, but they modify the balance. You are trying to protect *the balance* with locks. Once an account's balance is changed, there's no point in keeping that lock anymore. Additionally, I would suggest that it's not the responsibility of an account to know how to transfer to other accounts.

With that in mind, here are changes that eliminate the deadlock.

```
type Account(name:string) =
    let mutable balance = 1000
    let accountSync = new Object()

    member x.Withdraw amount = lock accountSync 
                                  (fun () -> balance <- balance - amount)
    member x.Deposit amount =  lock accountSync 
                                  (fun () -> balance <- balance + amount)

let transfer amount (fromAccount:Account) (toAccount:Account) =
    fromAccount.Withdraw(amount)
    toAccount.Deposit(amount)
```

Comment: I'm confused why you use a new Object to do locking while we can just lock the class object itself (i.e. lock x). I know your code works but I'm just not entirely sure why.

Comment: @user2431438 It's a preventative measure. As far as functionality goes, it really doesn't matter what instance you lock on as long as it's _the same instance_ for all operations affecting a given thing (in this case, the balance). Locking on the class instance itself, though, allows _anyone who can see the instance_ to lock it, potentially affecting the internal ability of the Account type to manage itself effectively (for example, somebody deadlocks on that instance and now that account is frozen). Creating a private instance within the type ensures that only the Account type can use it.

Comment: @user2431438: You should not lock externally visible objects because users of your library also can. Therefore, it is good practice to use a private object as Chris has.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, it's very clear. Just wondering what you mean by this sentence "If you have to acquire multiple locks at once, always acquire the locks in the same order".

Comment: @user2431438 Contending for a single resource is simple, you just wait until it's available. Contending for multiple resources is more difficult because, if they're acquired out of order, you may deadlock (as you experienced). Acquiring locks in order means that you are effectively waiting on a single resource.

Comment: @user2431438 If you're interested in learning more about concurrency, I highly recommend you read the entirety of [Joseph Albahari's Threading In C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). It's not specifically geared towards F# but it is extremely relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Chris explained the reason for the deadlock, but the solution must involve locking both accounts for the entirety of the transfer (assuming that a deposit could fail due to overdraft, etc). You're effectively striving for a form of transactional memory. Here's one way to do it:

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

type Account(name) =
  let mutable balance = 1000
  member val Name = name
  member __.Balance = balance
  member private __.Deposit amount =
    balance <- balance + amount
  member val private Lock = obj()
  member this.Transfer (toAccount: Account) amount =
    let rec loop() =
      let mutable retry = true
      if Monitor.TryEnter(this.Lock) then
        if Monitor.TryEnter(toAccount.Lock) then
          this.Deposit(-amount)
          toAccount.Deposit(amount)
          Monitor.Exit(toAccount.Lock)
          retry <- false
        Monitor.Exit(this.Lock)
      if retry then loop()
    loop()

let printLock = obj()

let doTransfers (acc:Account) (toAcc:Account) threadName = 
    for i in 1..100 do 
      acc.Transfer toAcc 100
      lock printLock (fun () ->
        printfn "%s - %s: %d, %s: %d" threadName acc.Name acc.Balance toAcc.Name toAcc.Balance)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    let acc1 = Account("Account1") 
    let acc2 = Account("Account2")
    Task.WaitAll [|
      Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> doTransfers acc1 acc2 "Thread 1")
      Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> doTransfers acc2 acc1 "Thread 2")
    |]
    printfn "\nDone."
    Console.Read()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I try not to use polling or mailbox for this task :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). The general solution is to sort your locks before taking them.